# In CUDA programming, is atomic function faster than reducing after calculating the intermediate results?

Tags: optimization, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu-atomics

Atomic functions (such as `atomic_add`) are widely used for counting or performing summation/aggregation in CUDA programming. However, I can not find information about the speed of atomic functions compared with ordinary global memory read/write.

Consider the following task,  where we want to calculate a floating-point array with 256K elements. Each element is the sum over 1000 intermediate variables which is calculated first. One approach is to use `atomic_add`; While another approach is to use a 256K*1000 temporary array for the intermediate results and then to reduce this array (by taking summation).

Is the first approach using atomic function faster than the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your specific case, even without you providing a concrete program, one does not need to know anything about the difference in latency or in bandwidth between atomic and non-atomic operations to rule out both your approaches: They are both quite inefficient.

You should have single blocks handling single output variables (or a small number of output variables), so that the sum of each 1,000 intermediate variables is not performed via global memory. You may want to read the "classic" presentation by Mark Harris:

- [Optimizing Parallel Reduction in CUDA](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf)

to get the basics. There have been  improvements over this in recent years, due to newer hardware capabilities. For a more recent actual implementation, see the [CUB library's block reduction primitive](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/classcub_1_1_block_reduce.html).

Also relevant: [CUDA: how to sum all elements of an array into one number within the GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42525713/cuda-how-to-sum-all-elements-of-an-array-into-one-number-within-the-gpu)

If you implement it this way, each output element will only be written to once. And even if the computation of the 1,000 intermediates somehow needs to be distributed among multiple blocks, for whatever reason you have not shared in the question -  you should still distribute it over a smaller number, rather than 1,000, so that the global-memory writes of the result take up a small enough fraction of the total computation time, that it is not worth bothering with something other than an atomic addition.